# Load .env and convert it to struct genericly with helper function

Tags: rust

I want to convert multiple env.variables to static struct.

I can do it mannually:

```
 Env {
        is_development: env::var("IS_DEVELOPMENT")
            .unwrap()
            .parse::<bool>()
            .unwrap(),
        server: Server {
            host: env::var("HOST").unwrap(),
            port: env::var("PORT")
                .unwrap()
                .parse::<u16>()
                .unwrap(),
        },
    }
```

But when there is multiple values, it's became bloated. Is there a way to make generic helper function that will give me value that i specify or panic? Something like this (or another solution):

```
    fn get_env_var<T>(env_var_name: String) -> T {
        // panic is ok here
        let var = env::var(env_var_name).unwrap(); 

        T::from(var)
    }



    get_env_var<u16>("PORT") // here i got u16
    get_env_var<bool>("IS_DEVELOPMENT") // here is my boolean
```

Full example

---

```
use crate::server::logger::log_raw;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::env;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Server {
    pub host: String,
    pub port: u16,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Env {
    pub is_development: bool,
    pub server: Server,
}
impl Env {
    pub fn init() -> Self {
        dotenv().expect(".env loading fail");

        // how can i specify what type i expect?
        fn get_env_var<T>(env_var_name: String) -> T {
            // panic is ok here
            let var = env::var(env_var_name).unwrap(); 

            T::from(var)
        }

        // instead this
        Env {
            is_development: env::var("IS_DEVELOPMENT")
                .unwrap()
                .parse::<bool>()
                .unwrap(),
            server: Server {
                host: env::var("HOST").unwrap(),
                port: env::var("PORT")
                    .unwrap()
                    .parse::<u16>()
                    .unwrap(),
            },
        }

        // do something like this
        /*
        Env {
            is_development: get_env_var<bool>("IS_DEVELOPMENT"),
            server: Server {
                host: get_env_var<String>("HOST"),
                port: get_env_var<u16>("PORT"),
            },
        }
        */
    }
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref ENV: Env = Env::init();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in your manual version, where you use [`str::parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse), you can have the same requirement as `str::parse`, which is [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html). So if you include the `T: FromStr` requirement, then you'll be able to do `var.parse::<T>()`.

```rust
use std::env;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn get_env_var<T>(env_var_name: &str) -> T
where
    T: FromStr,
    T::Err: Debug,
{
    let var = env::var(env_var_name).unwrap();
    var.parse::<T>().unwrap()
}
```

Then if you run the following by executing `PORT=1234 IS_DEVELOPMENT=true cargo run`.

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{}", get_env_var::<u16>("PORT"));
    println!("{}", get_env_var::<bool>("IS_DEVELOPMENT"));
}
```

Then it will output:

```
1234
true
```

---

Alternatively, you might want to be able to handle [`VarError::NotPresent`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/enum.VarError.html) and fallback to a default.

```rust
use std::env::{self, VarError};
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn get_env_var<T>(env_var_name: &str) -> Result<T, VarError>
where
    T: FromStr,
    T::Err: Debug,
{
    let var = env::var(env_var_name)?;
    Ok(var.parse().unwrap())
}
```

Now if you only executed `PORT=1234 cargo run`, then it would make it easier to do this:

```rust
let is_dev = get_env_var::<bool>("IS_DEVELOPMENT")
    .map_err(|err| match err {
        VarError::NotPresent => Ok(false),
        err => Err(err),
    })
    .unwrap();
println!("{:?}", is_dev);
```

---

If you want to fallback to [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) if [`VarError::NotPresent`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/enum.VarError.html):

```rust
fn get_env_var<T>(env_var_name: &str) -> T
where
    T: FromStr,
    T::Err: Debug,
    T: Default,
{
    let var = match env::var(env_var_name) {
        Err(VarError::NotPresent) => return T::default(),
        res => res.unwrap(),
    };

    var.parse().unwrap()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Rust genericity, inspired by Haskell's works through *traits* and specifically *trait bounds*. This means when you write

   ```rust
   fn get_env_var<T>(env_var_name: String) -> T
   ```

   since there is no trait bound on `T` there are essentially no capabilities for it (this is rather unlike C++).

   Therefore, as far as `rustc` is concerned, pretty much the only thing it can do with a `T` is... take one as parameter then return it as-is.

   Thus to do anything useful with a `T` (including creating one, whether from something else or *de novo*) you need to use the correct trait and provide the correct trait bounds.
2. The [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) trait is entirely the wrong trait to involve here: it specifies *total* (never-failing) conversions e.g. converting a u16 to a u32, which can never fail.

   Whether it's converting a String to a `bool` or a `u16`, the conversion is quite obviously less than total: there is an infinity of string values which are not sequences of decimal digits describing a number below 2^16.

In Rust, the signifier of failabibility tends to be `Try`. There is a `TryFrom` trait, however for historical reasons and as it documents in its signature [the `str::parse` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) is hooked on [the `FromStr` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html).

This means in order to declare that your `T` can be created from a string (and use the `parse` method to create one), you need to bound `T` to `FromStr`. And of course indicate that it may fail, and will return whatever error `T` generates when it *can't* be parsed from a string:

```rust
fn get_env_var<T: FromStr>(env_var_name: String) -> Result<T, T::Err> {
    let var = env::var(env_var_name).unwrap(); 

    var.parse()
}
```

Incidentally, taking a `String` as input is usually avoided unless you really have to[0]. Usually you'd take an `&str`, that's a lot more flexible as it can be used e.g. with string literals (which are of type `&'static str`).

So

```rust
fn get_env_var<T: FromStr>(env_var_name: &str) -> Result<T, T::Err> {
    let var = env::var(env_var_name).unwrap(); 

    var.parse()
}
```

[0] or for efficiency purposes *sometimes*

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was helpfull. I accepted another answer because i wanted to get rid of unwraps and just get my value or panic right away, so valentin answer got a little more points :)

Comment: Sure no worries.